# Spark filter with multiple columns working wrongly

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 30 rows and 10 columns. The column names are dynamically changing. This dataframe has null values in 8 columns for 2 rows which i am trying to remove these records with sparkSQL `filter` with `and` operator.

I see strange behavior with filter. When i frame my query with

```
df.filter('(`1Heavy Buyers` is null) and (`2Non Buyers` is null) and (`3Total Buyers` is null) and (`4Heavy Buyers` is null) and (`7Non Buyers` is null) and (`5Total Buyers` is null) and (`6Heavy Buyers` is null) and (`8Non Buyers` is null) and (`9otal Buyers` is null)')
```

i got back 2 records which is correct.

BUT when try with non null rows with

```
df.filter('(`1Heavy Buyers` is not null) and (`2Non Buyers` is not null) and (`3Total Buyers` is not null) and (`4Heavy Buyers` is not null) and (`7Non Buyers` is not null) and (`5Total Buyers` is not null) and (`6Heavy Buyers` is not null) and (`8Non Buyers` is not null) and (`9otal Buyers` is not null)')
```

i got back only 16 records which should be 28. In this case, filter is removing even if the one column has null value instead all the columns mentioned.

I am using spark 2.3.0.

I don't understand what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query that you ran meant that you intend to keep all the records in the dataframe where the values of all the six columns mentioned is null.

But, in the second query, all the records where the values of all the columns mentioned is not null will be kept. Which means, that even if only one of the columns has a null value, it will be filtered out. To obtain the result that you require, you can run the following query:

```
df.filter('(`1Heavy Buyers` is not null) or (`2Non Buyers` is not null) or (`3Total Buyers` is not null) or (`4Heavy Buyers` is not null) or (`7Non Buyers` is not null) or (`5Total Buyers` is not null) or (`6Heavy Buyers` is not null) or (`8Non Buyers` is not null) or (`9otal Buyers` is not null)')
```

The above query will give you your desired count of 28. Feel free to comment if you have any more doubts.

Comment: Ok got it, With my first query how can i remove only those two records from dataframe

Comment: To remove only the records in your first query, you can write the query as follows:

df.filter(not(col("1Heavy Buyers").isNull.and(col("2Non Buyers").isNull).and(col("3Total Buyers").isNull).and(col("4Heavy Buyers").isNull).and(col("7Non Buyers").isNull).and(col("5Total Buyers").isNull).and(col("6Heavy Buyers").isNull).and(col("8Non Buyers").isNull).and(col("9otal Buyers").isNull)))

Answer (score 0):

In case of sql we can also use below from JAVA

```
df.filter(not(functions.expr('(`1Heavy Buyers` is null) and (`2Non Buyers` is null) and (`3Total Buyers` is null) and (`4Heavy Buyers` is null) and (`7Non Buyers` is null) and (`5Total Buyers` is null) and (`6Heavy Buyers` is null) and (`8Non Buyers` is null) and (`9otal Buyers` is null)')))
```